# Numerical solution for transcendental equation in two variables

Tags: numerical-methods, transcendental-equations

I have this set of two equations

\begin{eqnarray}
e^{-35 (y-x)} & = & \frac{x}{y} \tag{1} \\ 
\frac{e^{-90 x}-e^{-90 y}}{e^{-142 x}-e^{-142 y}} & = & \frac{1892}{1007} \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

in the two real variables $x,y$, moreover I know from the Physical origin of these equations that $x,y\in[0,1]$. I am interested in numerical solutions, however
Mathematica for example doesn't give a solution.

Any hints how I can proceed here?

Comment: Here's a graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lz2e17dkxp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you say Mathematica does not give a numerical solution? Just use the command FindRoot[] taking initial approximations according to the graph shared by @MattiP. in the comments.This way you will be able to get approximations for all three solutions (one at a time).

Comment: You are completely right, FindRoot[] was the one I didn't try, https://ibb.co/xCLSsLJ Thank you and Matti!

Comment: @Moo Yes, I did find all three roots. For the one with $x=y$ you need to take an initial approximation such that $x_0 \ne y_0$.

Comment: There is no solution with $x=y$. The LHS of the second equation would not be defined.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut you are correct, that is not a solution of the initial equation, as it not defined for $x=y$, although we can give a meaning, by continuous extension.

Answer (score 3):

From the first  equation
$$y=-\frac{1}{35} W\left(-35 e^{-35 x} x\right)$$ Plug in the second to have only a function of $x$.

Plot it and notice the root close to $x=0.055$. Using Newton method, the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.05500000000 \\
 1 & 0.05459102858 \\
 2 & 0.05459414198 \\
 3 & 0.05459414216
\end{array}
\right)$$ and $y=0.01252009470$.

You have a second solution swapping $x$ and $y$ (the symmetry being obvious even without @Matti P.'s nice plot).